# Does $G\!-\!v_1 \simeq G\!-\!v_2$ mean an automorphism of $G$ maps $v_1$ to $v_2$?

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory

> For a simple undirected graph $G$, suppose we have two vertices $v_1$ and $v_2$ such that $G-v_1 \simeq G-v_2$. Does this necessarily mean that there is an automorphism of $G$ that maps $v_1$ to $v_2$?

This is just a condition that I've assumed to be true for awhile now without thinking too hard about whether or not it's actually true. Using the condition that $G-v_1 \simeq G-v_2$ has been a useful way to characterize two vertices as being "the same," but I was wondering if this actually corresponds to automorphisms of the graph.

Comment: G-v_1 is isomorphic to G-v_2 iff G-v_1 U{v_1} is isomorphic to G-v_2U{v_2} (without their attendant edges)

Comment: Note how obvious the other way around is. It seems there being an automorphism s.t f(v_1)=f(v_2) is stronger than simply G-v_1 is isomorphic to G-v_2. And in fact it is because this tells us nothing about the edge-structures of v_1 and v_2 which can vary wildly (in particular, their degrees can be different).

Comment: @Alephnull, well, if $G-v_1 \simeq G-v_2$, then the "edge structure" of $v_1$ and $v_2$ can't vary too wildly: they have to at least have the same degree. Otherwise  $G-v_1$ and $G-v_2$ would each have a different number of edges. But yeah, the converse of the statement is clearly true.

Comment: Oh man, you are right...

Comment: I think I forgot there was G on both sides... My argument works for G, H but that is trivial :(

Comment: It's curious to me that both of the examples given arise by the following construction: Let H be a graph with an automorphism f  (of order \geq 2) fixed, then remove all but two vertices: x, f(x) from some orbit of the action of f. In particular, its interesting that both examples ended up having the automorphism $G - v_1$ to $G-v_2$ send $v_2$ to $v_1$

Comment: Must there be a 1-1 homomorphism (either way)? What about an onto homomorphism?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. This graph is a counterexample:

[image: graph here]

Comment: Just curious, is this something you knew wasn't true so you had an idea of a counterexample laying around? Or was there a clever way you constructed this counterexample?

Comment: @MikePierce: I had to puzzle it out by hand. I've changed to an example that shows the principle in a clearer way; the one I posted first was not very clear due to being warped into ASCII art.

Comment: Does this have a 1-1 or onto endomorphism switching the vertices?

Answer (score 1):

Another counterexample, with the black vertices as $v_1$ and $v_2$. This graph has trivial automorphism group.

[image: counterexample]

Comment: The well-known simplest counterexample has $8$ vertices and $9$ edges: $$V=\{v_1,v_2,v_3 ,v_4, v_5,v_6,v_7,v_8\}$$ $$E=\{v_1v_2,v_2v_3,v_3v_4,v_4v_5,v_5v_6,v_6v_7,v_7v_8,v_1v_3,v_4v_6$$ The pseudosimilar vertices are $v_3$ and $v_6$; see the answer to the question which this is a duplicate of.

Comment: Does this have a 1-1 or onto morphism switching the vertices?